# Array echo doesn't print values retrieved from SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I got an array containing results from a SELECT statement. The weird thing is that I can print the array using:

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

I got :

```
[
  {
    "Habitacions": "3",
    "Tipus": "Piso",
    "Localitat": "El Vendrell",
    "Metres": "2",
    "Preu": "300",
    "Embarg": "0",
    "Operacio": "Lloguer",
    "Imatge1": "3_1.jpg",
    "Imatge2": "3_2.jpg",
    "Imatge3": "3_3.jpg",
    "Imatge4": "3_4.jpg",
    "Banys": "2",
    "Idelement": "3",
    "Tipus_EN": "Flat",
    "Tipus_CAT": "Pis",
    "Imatge1_Big": "3_1B.jpg",
    "Imatge2_Big": "3_2B.jpg",
    "Imatge3_Big": "3_3B.jpg",
    "Imatge4_Big": "3_4B.jpg",
    "Descripcio": "Test es",
    "ref": "3",
    "Obra": "0",
    "Descripcio_CAT": "Test cat",
    "Descripcio_EN": "Test en"
  }
]
```

But if I try this, I don't get anything echoed:

```
<?php echo $results['Descripcio_CAT']?>
```

Same for the rest of the keys.

Comment: What does `var_dump($results)` output?

Comment: $results[0]['Descripcio_CAT']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['Descripcio_CAT'];
```

for each row returned.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, is that your **json object** shows that `$results` is an array around an object.  This is what you need to do to access a value in that object.

```
<?php echo $results[0]->Descripcio_CAT; ?>
```

If you want the object alone you can assign it to a variable

```
<?php
$object = $results[0];
echo $object->Descripcio_CAT;
?>
```

Or if you will have a list of objects, you can use a `foreach` loop.

```
<?php
foreach($results as $object) {
    echo $object->Descripcio_CAT;
}
?>
```

If you just want to see the variable without knowing the contents you can `var_dump` it!

```
<?php var_dump($results); ?>
```